# chrome does not find any element in dom for selenium

Tags: selenium

[websitepicture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hMPJ.png)

Hi, Trying to find the selector for the element in the attached picture to click on it with selenium.
chrome cannot find it and chropath says:
"This element might be inside iframe from different src. Currently ChroPath doesn't support for them."

But I do not see any iframe or src.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG3Ag.png)

```
public void switchIntoIframe(WebElement el) throws myInterviewProjectExceptions {
 webDriver.switchTo().frame(el)
};
```

tried to pass the iframe:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"root\"]") 
private WebElement iframe;
```

to:

```
webDriver.switchTo().frame(el);
```

no help:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame: c7bb48a5-9eb0-410c-9593-9517d57d1490
```

Comment: tried to pass the iframe:
    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id=\"root\"]")
    private  WebElement iframe;

to:  webDriver.switchTo().frame(el);

no help:
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: Unable to locate frame: c7bb48a5-9eb0-410c-9593-9517d57d1490

Comment: It looks like the element is not inside an iframe. Have you tried using the normal CSS selector to click on the marked icon?

Comment: you are right it is not an iframe

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Can u take a look here?   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60660142/unable-to-locate-element-in-iframe-via-selenium

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try with the new version of ChroPath 6.0 and you can try //a[@class='module-link media']